# Special well ordering on every set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

[image]

Can someone explain to me the last line? How is this the desired well ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\leq_0$ be the restriction of the initial order on $B$ to $B_{a_0}$. Then $(B_{a_0},\leq_0)$ has the desired property. Moreover, $\psi:B\to B_{a_0}$ is an order isomorphism between $(B,\leq^*)$ and $(B_{a_0},\leq_0)$, so  $(B,\leq^*)$ will also have the desired property.

---

EDIT: Let's see why $B_{a_0}$ has the desired property: if $x\in B_{a_0}=\left\{y:y<a_0\right\}$, then $y<a_0$. Since $a_0=\min\left\{a:|B_a|=|B|\right\}$, then $y\not\in\left\{a:|B_a|=|B|\right\}$, so $|B_y|<|B|=|B_{a_0}|$. This is precisely what we want.

Comment: How is restriction the desired order?

Comment: I'm not saying the restricted order, which is on $B_{a_0}$ (defined by $a\leq_0 b\iff a\leq b$), is the desired one on $B$, because that doesn't make sense. I'm saying that $(B_{a_0},\leq_0)$ has the following property: For every $a\in B_{a_0}$, the set $\left\{x\in B_{a_0}:x<a\right\}$ has cardinality strictly smaller than that of $B_{a_0}$. Then we define a *new* order $\leq^*$ on $B$ which makes it isomorphic to $(B_{a_0},\leq_0)$, and this property is preserved by isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, I know that's what you were trying to say, but I don't understand how?

Comment: @SahibaArora It is not a restriction. Consider the ordering of the natural numbers where you first list (in the usual order) the even numbers, then the odd primes, then the odd squares of primes, then the rest. This is a well-ordering. The number 3 is the first such that its predecessors (the even numbers) form a countably infinite set. You then pick your favorite bijection between the even numbers and the natural numbers, and use it to "translate" the well-ordering on the even numbers. My favorite bijection maps 0 to 1, 2 to 0, 4 to 7, 6 to 2, etc... (cont.)

Comment: @SahibaArora How $(B_{a_0},\leq_0)$ has the "desired property" or how is "the desired property" preserved under isomorphisms?

Comment: (cont.) This means that the well-ordering you are defining on $\mathbb N$ is $1<0<7<2<\dots$

Comment: I don't understand how $B_{a_0}$ has the desired property?

Comment: @SahibaArora Ok. I added an explanation for this.

Comment: @SahibaArora Do you understand why $\psi$ is an order isomorphism?

Comment: I understood your explanation of translation of the ordering.